# Couldnt find ab-cd config file for this filepath:config.properties. <phase>package</phase><goals> <goal>shade</goal> </goals>

Tags: maven, jar, package, runnable

mvn package - ruunable jar file is unable to locate this properties file. In  Eclipse my application runs fine but after i create mvn package. runnable jar file is giving me me null pointer. I used 7zip to view the create runnable jar file i see config.properties is correctly added in jar but my ruunable application jar is not picking it up.

I am getting null pointer here..... Its coming from JAR file which i cant edit.

```
ClassLoader classLoader = super.getClass().getClassLoader();
        File file = new File(classLoader.getResource(fileName).getFile());
        if (file.exists()) {
            reader = new FileReader(file);
            instance.properties.load(reader);
        } else {
            System.out
                    .println("Couldnt find ab-cd config file for this filepath:"
                            + fileName);
```

Couldnt find ab-cd config file for this filepath:config.properties            Oct 18, 2015 3:47:24 PM org.springframework.ws.soap.saaj.SaajSoapMessageFactory afterPropertiesSet                                                              INFO: Creating SAAJ 1.3 MessageFactory with SOAP 1.1 Protocol                   java.lang.NullPointerException                                                          at java.net.URI$Parser.parse(URI.java:3004)                                     at java.net.URI.(URI.java:577)                                            at java.net.URI.create(URI.java:839)                                            at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate$1.getDestination(WebServiceTemplate.java:213)                                                          at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.getDefaultUri(WebServiceTemplate.java:188)                                                             at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.marshalSendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:380)                                                     at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.marshalSendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:372)                                                     at

My pom.xml file to build it

```
    <build>

<finalName>AE</finalName>
    <plugins>

        <!-- download source code in Eclipse, best practice -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.9</version>
            <configuration>
                <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                <downloadJavadocs>false</downloadJavadocs>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <!-- Set a compiler level -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>${jdk.version}</source>
                <target>${jdk.version}</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>




    <!-- Maven Shade Plugin -->
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.3</version>
      <executions>
         <!-- Run shade goal on package phase -->
        <execution>
        <phase>package</phase>
        <goals>
            <goal>shade</goal>
        </goals>



        <configuration>
          <transformers>
            <!-- add Main-Class to manifest file -->

                            <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">

                <mainClass>com.abcdedf.ghi.main.Start</mainClass>
                 <manifestEntries>
      <Class-Path>.</Class-Path>
    </manifestEntries>
            </transformer>
          </transformers>
        </configuration>
          </execution>
      </executions>
    </plugin>
    </plugins>
```

Comment: I am not sure where i have to place that config.properties file so that my runnable jar can pick it. Please help!

Comment: In the jar file, where does `config.properties` reside? In the root?

Comment: I think you cannot treat resources from the classpath as files - since the mostly reside inside of a jar. So I would try to load the properties from the inputstream instead of wrapping it into a file: properties.load(classloader.getResourceAsStream("")). If you want to use filepath: (or need to) you may need to copy the resource from the classpath into that file first. But there is classpath: as well for flyway configuration - so all this might not be necessary to run flyway commands.

Comment: I resolved it. Actually i need to place my config.properties along with the generated *.jar. Thanks for reply though !!